# How to read the head of a .gz file using AWS S3 , without downloading the file

Tags: amazon-web-services, unix, amazon-s3

I am trying to read the head of a gz file using awscli without downloading. I am using the command

```
aws s3api get-object --bucket mybucket_name --key path/to/the/file.log.gz --range bytes=0-10000 /dev/stdout | zless
```

which I found in the [link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983769/head-command-for-aws-s3-to-view-file-contents?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983769/head-command-for-aws-s3-to-view-file-contents?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I am able to read head of simple txt files, but how to do it for .gz files. Or any other way using some other tool if it can be accomplished?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28363188/136285

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but combination of [S3 select](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-glacier-select/) and @malat suggested approach could lead to you a solution.

Comment: Try with a variation of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49425766/2732674

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do is :-

```
aws s3api get-object --bucket bucket_name --key path/to/file.txt  --range bytes=0-10000 /path/to/local/t3.txt | cat t3 | head -1
```

For the gz file , you can do

```
aws s3api get-object --bucket bucket_name --key path/to/file.gz  --range bytes=0-10000 /path/to/local/t3 | zless t3 | head -1
```